# Error in Excel. Incorrect syntax near','. VBA to SQL

Tags: sql, vba, excel

Help, where is the error?

I am sending data from an Excel sheet with VBA to SQL

Error appears

> Incorrect syntax near ','.

```
Function Query_Data_Desembolsos()
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Field As ADODB.Field

    Dim Col As Long

    Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset

Final = GetUltimoR(Hoja1)

For Fila = 2 To Final

    AGENCIA = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 1)
    CODIGO_AGENCIA = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 2)
    CODIGO_SUB_APLICACION = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 3)
    PRESTAMO = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 4)
    NO_PRESTAMO = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 5)
    DESC_MONEDA = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 6)
    TIPO_PRESTAMO_I = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 7)
    TIPO_PRESTAMO_II = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 8)
    NOMBRE_CLIENTE = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 9)

    APERTURA = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 10)
    APERTURA = Format(APERTURA, "yyyy-mm-dd")

    VENCIMIENTO = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 11)
    VENCIMIENTO = Format(VENCIMIENTO, "yyyy-mm-dd'")

    TASA_TOTAL = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 12)

    MONTO_INICIAL = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 13)
    'MONTO_INICIAL = Format(MONTO_INICIAL, "currency")

    MONTO_LPS = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 14)
    'MONTO_LPS = Format(MONTO_LPS, "currency")

    CODIGO_EJECUTIVO = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 15)
    OFICIAL_CREDITO = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 16)
    CANAL = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 17)
    AGENCIA_ORIGEN_PRESTAMO = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 18)
    NOMBRE_AGENCIA = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 19)
    CODIGO_TIPO_CREDITO = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 20)
    NOMBRE_TIPO_CREDITO = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 21)
    CODIGO_TIPO_GARANTIA = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 22)
    NOMBRE_GARANTIA = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 23)
    TIPO_DE_CREDITO = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 24)
    COD_OPI = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 25)
    NOMBRE_EMPRESA_OPI = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 26)
    TIPO_DESEMBOLSO = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 27)
    Estructura_Mes = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 28)
    OBS_Desembolsos = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 29)




     SQL = "INSERT INTO TBL_BNK_AUTO_DESEMBOLSOS values('" & AGENCIA & "','" & CODIGO_AGENCIA & "','" & CODIGO_SUB_APLICACION & "','" & PRESTAMO & "','" & NO_PRESTAMO & "','" & DESC_MONEDA & "','" & TIPO_PRESTAMO_I & "','" & TIPO_PRESTAMO_II & "','" & NOMBRE_CLIENTE & "'," & APERTURA & "  ," & VENCIMIENTO & ",'" & TASA_TOTAL & "','" & MONTO_INICIAL & "','" & MONTO_LPS & "','" & CODIGO_EJECUTIVO & "','" & OFICIAL_CREDITO & "','" & CANAL & "','" & AGENCIA_ORIGEN_PRESTAMO & "','" & NOMBRE_AGENCIA & "' , '" & CODIGO_TIPO_CREDITO & "' , '" & NOMBRE_TIPO_CREDITO & "' , '" & CODIGO_TIPO_GARANTIA & "' , '" & NOMBRE_GARANTIA & "' , '" & TIPO_DE_CREDITO & "' , '" & COD_OPI & "' , '" & NOMBRE_EMPRESA_OPI & "' , '" & TIPO_DESEMBOLSO & "' , '" & Estructura_Mes & "' , '" & OBS_Desembolsos & "');"
    RS.Open SQL, CN


Next

    RS.Open "SELECT * FROM TBL_BNK_AUTO_DESEMBOLSOS", CN


End Function
```

Comment: Check the quotation mark in this bit: `VENCIMIENTO = Format(VENCIMIENTO, "yyyy-mm-dd'")`

Comment: A useful hint is to breakpoint on the line after setting your SQL variable, print out the SQL variable to the immediate window, and copy and paste the sql statement into an editor with SQL syntax highlighting. That should help see any issues.

Comment: Also when building a string like this its good to make sure none of your variables include a single quote within them (') as this will close your string prematurely in the SQL command.

Comment: Thanks. this was the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider parameterizing your query using an ADO Command to execute the action query not by `recordset.Open`. Parameterization is an industry best practice for security against sql injection, efficiency in binding values to a prepared statement, and even avoids needing to enclose values with quotes from application layer code like Excel VBA.

Below assumes all parameters are strings of 255 length. Adjust [types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/datatypeenum) as needed:

```vb
...

' NUMBER OF QUESTION MARK PLACEHOLDERS = NUMBER OF VALUES
strSQL = "INSERT INTO TBL_BNK_AUTO_DESEMBOLSOS VALUES (?, ?, ?, ...)"

For Fila = 2 To Final
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

    With cmd
       .ActiveConnection = CN
       .CommandText = strSQL
       .CommandType = adCmdText
    End With

    ' BIND VALUES TO PLACEHOLDERS
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("param0", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, AGENCIA)    
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("param1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, CODIGO_AGENCIA)    
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("param2", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, CODIGO_SUB_APLICACION)    
    ...

    ' EXECUTE ACTION QUERY
    cmd.Execute

Next Fila
```